# git tab space difference issue

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket

For some reason, if I indent anything with a tab in any file like this:

Before:

```
something {
text
}
```

After:

```
something {
    text
}
```

git diff shows me this instead:

```
something {
        text
}
```

I've tried couple different editors (Eclipse, Gedit), but the outcome is the same. My question is: why does git sees a tab as 8 spaces instead of 4? How do I fix this?

I've tried this:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -x4'
```

So now the tab size in `git diff` is correct, but when I push it to remote repository (Bitbucket), it still shows as 8 spaces instead of 4. I don't understand. When I worked on windows everything was fine, but now that I've switched to Ubuntu I have this problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is an ongoing issue on Bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6207/fix-tab-size-in-source-code-viewer-bb-7488 so it has nothing to do with git itself.

Comment: So when you said `git diff shows me` that meant "when I browse on bitbucket's site" ?

Comment: @AD7six No, initially git diff setting was off as well, but I've changed the config to fix it.